# What are the supported authentication headers for the HTTP Request Action?

Tags: install4j

Today I have a question about the HTTP Request action of install4j versions 6.1.X. When we do a request against a secured rest endpoint a dialog is displayed to collect the credentials of the user. That work fine for the Basic authentication mechanism. Now we have a scenario to challenge against a kerberos authentication mechanism like it is the standard for single-sign-on system architectures. Is this supported by the HTTP Request action?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no support for any other authentication mechanisms other than basic authentication.

Comment: So for our purpose we have to implement our own HTTP request action. Is it recommended to extend the existing action of install4j?